# stop img from being transformed beyond div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, transform, css-transforms

I have an image that sits in a div. The image is almost always bigger than the div which is fine, as the overflow is hidden. I want the user to be able to adjust the visible part of the image (within the div/window) but stop them from adjusting the xy coordinates past the boundaries of the div.

```
function Crop() {
    const [imgX, setImgX] = useState(0)
    const [imgY, setImgY] = useState(0)

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="window">
                <img src={image} alt="" transform: `translate(${imgX}px, ${imgY}px)`/>
            </div>
            <div>
               <button onClick={() => {setThumbY(thumbY - 10)}}>UP</button>
               <button onClick={() => { setThumbY(thumbY + 10)}}>DOWN</button>
               <button onClick={() => {setThumbX(thumbX - 10)}}>LEFT</button>
               <button onClick={() => {setThumbX(thumbX + 10)}}>RIGHT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The transforming works, but it also lets me who move the picture up and out of the div completely. Now, is there a way to set boundaries for transforming and make those boundaries the moment when the picture's edge moves past (or is about to move past) the div's edge?

Or I was thinking every picture will have a different size, so maybe every picture needs their own constraints based on dimensions, but I can't seem to figure that out either. Is there a simple way to do this? To keep the all edges of the image within the div/window, but still allow for transforming the overflow?

Let's say the window is 300px by 300px and the image is 500px by 500px. There's an extra 200px on both sides to manipulate within the window before it moves past the boundaries. How am I able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**The component now handle ranges for `width` and `height` separately.**

It also attempts to get the natural size of `img` if no `imageSize` is provided on `load` event.

```
const [imgNatural, setImgNatural] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

const handleImageLoad = () =>
  setImgNatural({
    width: imgRef.current.naturalWidth,
    height: imgRef.current.naturalHeight,
  });
```

```
<Crop image={url} boxSizeX={300} boxSizeY={200} step={10} />
```

**Original**

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but here is a quick example.

It sets the limits by passing defined sizes for image and display box to the component, and disable the buttons when the image is about to move past a certain range.

```
<Crop image={url} boxSize={300} imageSize={500} step={10} />
```

It calculates the moveable `range` simply by:

```
const range = Math.abs((boxSize - imageSize) / 2)
```

It does cover the cases of image both bigger and smaller than the display box, but perhaps this can be further improved by taking `step` into calculation.

The below example runs in the snippet for convenience.

```js
function Crop({ image, boxSizeX, boxSizeY, imageSizeX, imageSizeY, step }) {
  const [imgX, setImgX] = React.useState(0);
  const [imgY, setImgY] = React.useState(0);

  const imgRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [imgNatural, setImgNatural] = React.useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const handleImageLoad = () =>
    setImgNatural({
      width: imgRef.current.naturalWidth,
      height: imgRef.current.naturalHeight,
    });

  //  These and related logic can be improved by also considering step
  const rangeX = imageSizeX
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeX - imageSizeX) / 2)
    : imgNatural.width
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeX - imgNatural.width) / 2)
    : 100;

  const rangeY = imageSizeY
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeY - imageSizeY) / 2)
    : imgNatural.height
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeY - imgNatural.height) / 2)
    : 100;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {imgNatural.width && imgNatural.height ? (
          <p>{`Natural image size is ${imgNatural.width}px * ${imgNatural.height}px `}</p>
        ) : (
          <p>Loading image...</p>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setImgY((prev) => (prev -= step));
          }}
          disabled={imgY <= -rangeY ? true : false}
        >
          UP
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setImgY((prev) => (prev += step));
          }}
          disabled={imgY >= rangeY ? true : false}
        >
          DOWN
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setImgX((prev) => (prev -= step));
          }}
          disabled={imgX <= -rangeX ? true : false}
        >
          LEFT
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setImgX((prev) => (prev += step));
          }}
          disabled={imgX >= rangeX ? true : false}
        >
          RIGHT
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        className="window"
        style={{ width: `${boxSizeX}px`, height: `${boxSizeY}px` }}
      >
        <img
          src={image}
          alt=""
          ref={imgRef}
          onLoad={handleImageLoad}
          style={{
            width: imageSizeX ? `${imageSizeX}px` : "auto",
            height: imageSizeY ? `${imageSizeY}px` : "auto",
            transform: `translate(${imgX}px, ${imgY}px)`,
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Crop
        image={"https://picsum.photos/400/300"}
        boxSizeX={300}
        boxSizeY={200}
        step={10}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.window {
 background-color: pink;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can I make this change based on the image inside the div tho. If I upload a random picture and don't want to keep changing the sizes, I mean.

Comment: @Yehuda I updated the snippet so that when `imageSize` is not provided, the component attempts to get `naturalWidth` from the image. It relies on the `load` event to read the image though, so I think providing the size of picture when possible is still preferable.

Comment: the uploading part will be handled on the client side, and they might not know the image dimensions, or want to find out that information.

Comment: @Yehuda I see, then I think this current approach works fine for the use case. I have updated the snippets so it handles `range` for `width` and `height` separately, allowing rectangular images to be used. Hope that it helps.